# C struct - error: unknown type name between two files

Tags: c, gcc, struct

I have 3 files:

-file 1 has table1 struct and a function that acts on table 2 structs

```
// header file table 1
#include "table_2.h" 
typedef struct{...}table1;

void * doSomethingGivenTable2(table2 * t2);
```

-file 2 has table2 struct and a function that acts on table 1 structs

```
// header file table 2
#include "table_1.h"
typedef struct{...}table2;

void * doSomethingGivenTable1(table1 * t1);
```

-file 3 uses both of the structs from file 1 and 2

```
#include "table_1.h"
#include "table_2.h" 
// this is fine because I am including both of them in a separate file
```

What happens in file 3 is fine, but file 1 and file 2 produce `error: unknown type name` for the structs since I am including the header of each file in the other file. I am also defining functions that use the other's structs. Can I fix this while leaving both of the functions in their places? If not, then what alternatives do I have?

Thanks

Comment: Show the full error including source line number. And use `"` to include "custom" headers.

Comment: Read up on "forward declaration", and "header include guards".

Comment: @EugeneSh.I don't understand what you mean. Should I include "custom" in my answer or in the question?

Comment: @DevSolar thanks. I will do.

Comment: What Eugene meant is that `#include <...>` is usually reserved for standard library headers, with `#include "..."` used for everything else. Virtually all compilers will not make a practical difference between the two, but it is good style.

Comment: Oh thanks. Makes sense @DevSolar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need structure tags so you can `typedef` an identifier for an incomplete structure type. To avoid defining the same `typedef` identifier multiple times, the `typedef` declarations can be moved into a common header file as follows:

**table_common.h**:

```
#ifndef TABLE_COMMON_H_INCLUDED
#define TABLE_COMMON_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct table1 table1;
typedef struct table2 table2;

#endif
```

**table_1.h**:

```
#ifndef TABLE_1_H_INCLUDED
#define TABLE_1_H_INCLUDED

#include "table_common.h"

struct table1 {
   ...
};

void * doSomethingGivenTable2(table2 * t2);

#endif
```

**table_2.h**:

```
#ifndef TABLE_2_H_INCLUDED
#define TABLE_2_H_INCLUDED

#include "table_common.h"

struct table2 {
   ...
};

void * doSomethingGivenTable1(table1 * t1);

#endif
```

**Notes**:

1. The `table1` in `struct table1` is a structure tag. I used the same name for the structure tag and its associated `typedef` identifier. The same name can be used because the namespace for structure tags is different to the namespace for other identifiers. However, there is no requirement for the structure tag name to match the typedef identifier so you can make them different if you want.
2. The header files I wrote use a common preprocessor trick to avoid problems when the same header file is included more than once.  The macros defined for this trick are known as "guard macros".

Answer (score 2):

You can separate the `typedef` from the actual `struct` definition like this. This allows the compiler to know that `table1` is a datatype it can expect to find, but that it will get the full definition of it later, so not to worry that it doesn't know what it actually is yet.

```
#ifndef TABLE1_H
#define TABLE1_H

typedef struct table1_s table1;

#include "table2.h"

struct table1_s
  {
  // contents of struct
  };

#endif
```

As an aside, if you have functions that only make use of (for example) `table2`, they should be declared in the same include file as `table2`, not `table1`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the struct name in the header of the opposite table as well, like

`typedef struct table1 table1;`

inside table2.h and vice versa.

Comment: But this is the case for me right now. Each is defined in the header file. I will change my question to reflect this

Comment: Is `table1 table1` a typo or is it how it is supposed to be done? Because now I am getting 'conflicting types for 'table1'' and the same for table2

Comment: @Ahmed You probably have multiple `typedef` declarations for the same identifier. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51248681/5264491) for a way to resolve that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use forward declaration.

In your file 1, add the following statement:

```
typedef struct tbl2 table2;
```

In your file 2, add the following statement:

```
typedef struct tbl1 table1;
```

In your file 3, add the following statements:

```
typedef struct tbl1 table1;
typedef struct tbl2 table2;
```

This is known as forward declaration, which tells your compiler that these structures are available elsewhere and not to complain.

Comment: I am getting this now -> `warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration`, and I think because of the warning I still got the same error of the unknown types. Just to clarify, should I put this before or after the original declaration?

Comment: `typedef struct table2;` doesn't really do anything beyond what `struct table2;` does. Perhaps you meant to declare a typedef name?